# Using 4bit PowerPC CR0 register from GCC

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, powerpc

I want to create functions that save/restore state of the CPU registers via GCC compiler. 
In PowerPC it's 8 conditional 4 bit registers ('cr0'-'cr7'), I want to get their values and save it in memory. My solution (which is not working):

```
register int cr0 __asm__("cr0");
```

This is working with general purpose registers ('r1'-'r30'), after register is defined so, one can use it in any way.
But when compiling the code above, it fails with the following error:

```
hello.c: In function ‘foo’:
hello.c:58:22: error: register specified for ‘cr0’ isn’t suitable for data type
         register int cr0 __asm__("cr0");
```

I assume that trouble is that cr0 register is 4bit wide, so it can'not be placed into 32bit int variable. (16 and 8 bits is failed too)

How to handle this problem? Is there any workaround with 4bits integers in GCC?  Or how to address full `cr` 32bit register, not only it's parts?

Comment: It's unlikely you can manually manage gcc's use of different parts of the condition-register.  Register-asm variables only work with general-purpose integer registers, or FP registers for FP variables.

Comment: Be aware of the **[ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) conventions** for your particular platform. They matter a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create functions that save/restore state of the CPU registers via GCC compiler.

Register-`asm` local variables are useless for this purpose.

They're only guaranteed to be in the specified register when it's used as an operand for an extended-asm statement ([gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html)).  This allows the compiler to spill/reload the register across function calls if needed.

More importantly for your case, assigning a new value to a register-asm local variable inside a function will cause the compiler to save/restore the caller's value in the function prologue/epilogue.  See [this example on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+call_clobbered(int+x)+%7B%0A++++register+int+a+asm(%22r2%22)+%3D+123%3B%0A++++asm(%22%22+::+%22r%22(a))%3B+//+force+the+compiler+to+have+the+value+in+the+register%0A++++return+a%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+call_preserved(int+x)+%7B%0A++++register+int+a+asm(%22r22%22)+%3D+123%3B%0A++++asm(%22%22+::+%22r%22(a))%3B+//+force+the+compiler+to+have+the+value+in+the+register%0A++++return+a%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:41.119907337215245,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:ppcg48,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3+-mregnames',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'PowerPC+gcc+4.8.5+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:58.516791210652464,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
int call_clobbered(int x) {
    register int a asm("r2") = 123;
    asm("" :: "r"(a)); // force the compiler to have the value in the register
    return a;
}

   # gcc4.8.5 -O3 -mregnames
    li %r2,123
    li %r3,123      # return-value register
    blr


int call_preserved(int x) {
    register int a asm("r22") = 123;
    asm("" :: "r"(a)); // force the compiler to have the value in the register
    return a;
}

   # gcc4.8.5 -O3 -mregnames
    stwu %r1,-48(%r1)
    stw %r22,8(%r1)     # save caller's r22
    li %r22,123
    li %r3,123
    lwz %r22,8(%r1)     # restore caller's r22
    addi %r1,%r1,48     # deallocate stack space
    blr
```

So you might be able to make code that happens to work for *saving* your caller's registers, but without inline asm you won't be able to write code that restores registers as part of a context-switch.

Besides, you don't want to save/restore all 8 nibbles of `CR` separately anyway!  Save the whole 32-bit register like a normal person.  Or better, make your context-switch function an actual function that compiler-generated code calls, so you don't have to save/restore any call-clobbered registers.  (Because the compiler is *expecting* your function to clobber all those registers before it returns.)

I don't know PowerPC calling conventions, but I'm guessing all of CR is call-clobbered.  On ISAs with only a single FLAGS / condition-code register, it's always call-clobbered.

---

If you do need to save/restore CR, you probably have to write your whole function in pure asm, because any compiler-generated code could clobber CR after you restore it.

To save/restore the whole CR, see [this PPC ISA quick reference](http://www.tentech.ca/downloads/other/PPC_Quick_Ref_Card-Rev1_Oct12_2010.pdf).

Use **`mfcr r1`** (*move from CR*) to copy all 32 bits to an integer register (which you can then store to memory).  Use **`mtcr r1`** to *move to CR* when restoring.  Works with any register; `r1` is just an example.

Comment: The problem is that I put calls to my context switch function manually in binary code arbitrary position, so call-clobbered regs are not saved by compiler. I want to save all call-clobbered registers and restore them. 
As I see, it can be done only by asm inlines.
But how can I access to all CR register? It isnt seems like valid register name to compiler

Comment: Right, you can't get the compiler to generate code to save/restore CR, you'll have to write it in asm.  Updated my answer with the `mfcr` and `mtcr` instructions you'll need.  Don't forget to save/restore LR, CTR, and any other special-purpose registers, too.

Comment: CR2-4 are non-volatile across function calls.

Answer (score 3):

The gcc extension `register int cr0 __asm__("cr0");` is used to assign a specific register for a C variable (local or even global). It cannot be used for your purpose because the register you mention is indeed inappropriate to store values of type `int`. There are other restrictions on the set of registers that can be used this way, it is not a generic way to *save* register values.

You should use inline assembly to read the values of these special registers into local variables and save those somewhere else.